# Why does Windows Live Mail strip attachments of ONE contact?

Tags: windows-7, email, windows-live-mail

I am trying to solve a very weird issue on one laptop: It has Windows 7 x64 running and is using Windows Live Mail. One specific contact, always gets the attachments stripped/removed. For reference, the file is an JPG picture and a XLS file.

**What I have tried :**

- Checking on the online web interface of the email service provider if the attachment is there ; and it is actually there and I can download it from the inbox.
- Sending the same attachment from other email addresses to this laptops email address. Even with other contacts, attachments are downloaded. With other emails addresses, this winmail.dat is downloaded without problem.
- Adding this contact into the Safe Sender List and adding the domain to the Safe Sender List.
- Restarting ;)
- Check the attachment type and enable Windows Live Mail to receive ANY attachment file types.
- Check the Security SPAM filter settings ; they are off ! Also, check the first point again - The ISP is not blocking the attachment as it is visible and downloadable from the webmail interface.
- Creating a profile on Microsoft Outlook with the laptops email account : It contains the attachment.

How can I get Windows Live Mail to download attachments for this contact ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Live Mail doesn't delete attachments. It is probably a matter of the
format of the message created by that one contact not being correctly
understood by Windows Live Mail.

One likely case is that a message with an attachment is sent using
Microsoft Office Outlook or Microsoft Exchange Client using
their proprietary RTF format, called TNEF-encoding.

To check, select one of the messages and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>
to reveal the message source.
Attachments will be at the bottom, separated from other parts of the message by
a blank line, followed by a line starting with at least two hyphens. They will normally have a `Content-Type:` declaration telling you what sort of attachment
you're dealing with.

You can check for TNEF-encoding
by looking for a declaration that looks like this :

```
Content-Type: application/ms-tnef;
```

Viewing the message source will also probably tell you which client was used to compose and send the message. Outlook may for example add a header
similar to :

```
X-Mailer: Microsoft Outlook 14.0
```

I counsel using a more sophisticated email client than the simple-minded
Windows Live Mail, or a webmail service such as Gmail or Hotmail.

[Source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/livemail-email-lost/windows-live-mail-deleting-attachments-from-a/9b230e4c-d8b2-4461-b971-19fc43885fca)

Comment: I installed another email client.